# Oracle : Unique Key and Primary Key

Tags: oracle, ora-00001

Consider the table which contains unique Key and Primary Key .the tables already contains data.If i added any rows to the table i received an error (ORA - 0001) which is due to the duplicate value is added to the Primary Key or Unique Key .Here i am not able to identify whether the error is due to the addition of duplicate value to the Primary Key or Unique Key.Can anyone suggest me how to identify this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format of the [ORA-00001 message](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14219/e0.htm#sthref17) is:

ORA-00001: unique constraint violated (string.string)

where `string.string` is `schema.constraint_name`.  This is why it is good practice to give our constraints helpful names.

```
create table t23
   ( id number not null
     , col1 varchar2(30)
     , col2 date
     , constraint t23_pk primary key (id)
     , constraint t23_uk unique (col1)
  )
/
```

Answer (score 2):

The error displays the constraint that was violated .
The message shd look like:

> ORA-00001: unique constraint
>   (string.string) violated

where (string.string) will be the name of the constraints